# How to make a True Random with equal chance in AS3?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, random, flashdevelop

I'm developing a rock-paper-scissor game player vs computer. There's nothing special except player playing 3 rounds per game.

I'm using this code to generate random number from 1 to 3

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+3-1))+1
```

1 = Scissor, 2 = Paper, 3 = Rock

I'm not sure but this code favor on Number 2.

Meaning the computer generate **Paper-Paper-Paper** so the player notice it and taking the advantage and select **scissor-scissor-scissor**. I bet you will do it also.

How can I generate real randomness in AS3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct, although it could be simplified to just `Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 1`. That will return numbers between 1 and 3 and the distribution should be uniform (unless there's a big bug in the Flash player).

You can verify this by looping on the number and counting the occurrence of each number. For example:

```
var count = [0,0,0];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 1;
    count[n-1]++;
}

trace(count);
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.